# Linq To Entities, few key value pairs in where condition

Tags: c#, .net-core, linq-to-entities

I do have a "Tracking" table and "TrackingDetails" table.

Tracking Table

```
Id      DateTime              Description
100     2022-12-08T10:53      Package Picked Up
101     2022-12-08T10:59      Package is in lorry
```

TrackingDetails Table [TrackingId is the foreign key of Tracking table's Id column)

```
Id      TrackingId            Key                   Value
45      100                   Location              Davis place
46      100                   ResponsiblePerson     John
47      100                   ReferenceNo           102A788
48      100                   Status                PickedUp
49      101                   Location              Torington
50      101                   ResponsiblePerson     Driver : Mick
51      101                   ReferenceNo           102A788
52      101                   Status                InTransit
```

I need to check whether, is there a record from referenceno=102A788 and status=PickedUp condition.

```
 //Method 1
 var isExist = _TrackingRepository.GetAll().Include(x => x.Details).Where(x => x.Details.Where(y => (y.Key == "ReferenceNo" && y.Value == "102A788") && (y.Key == "Status" && y.Value == "PickedUp")).Any()).Any();
```

But this query always return **false** even there is a record available in the database.
(Expected value is true)

Then I try below.

```
//Method 2
var isExist = _TrackingRepository.GetAll().Include(x => x.Details).Where(x => x.Details.Where(y => y.Key == "ReferenceNo").Any())
                .Include(x => x.Details).Where(x => x.Details.Where(y => y.Value == "102A788").Any()).Any();
```

This returns **True** and works as expected. But my question is, isn't there any other way to query my condition? I felt bit ugly on this 2nd method and seems like nonperformative. In here I check only 2 conditions. But if I check for 10 conditions, I have to repeat *.Include(x => x.Details)* for 10 times.

Can any expert comment on this please?

Comment: You need `||` instead of `&&`. Both conditions can't be true in the same record.

Comment: Also, side note, remove the `Include`s. They're not necessary.

Comment: I would check the generated SQL to see how that looks to say if it's performant or not.   The fact that you have a bit of extra typing in C# is not really a problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your method. First, the condition y.Key == "ReferenceNo" && y.Value == "102A788" && (y.Key == "Status" && y.Value == "PickedUp") will always return false because a record cannot have the same key and value for both "ReferenceNo" and "Status". You can use the && operator to check if a record has the "ReferenceNo" and "Status" keys, but you will need to check the values separately.

Here is one way you can modify your method to check for the correct values:

```
var isExist = _TrackingRepository.GetAll()
.Include(x => x.Details)
.Where(x => x.Details
    .Any(y => y.Key == "ReferenceNo" && y.Value == "102A788")
    && x.Details
    .Any(y => y.Key == "Status" && y.Value == "PickedUp")
).Any();
```

This method will check if there is any record in the TrackingDetails table that has both the "ReferenceNo" key with the value "102A788" and the "Status" key with the value "PickedUp". This should return true if there is a record that matches these conditions.

Comment: Thanks @sebastian for putting your worth time for this question. This looks good. But if I need to make this dynamic, how may I change this? Sometimes I need to check for 2 conditions, other time I need to check for 3 conditions. This is like querying. Basically frontend JSON sends few key values pairs (cannot say exactly how many key values pairs) and with the backend we need to give result according to that.